# How can I remap my command key to my control key?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, synergy

In short, here's my predicament:

I'm running 2 computers [synergy'd](http://synergy-foss.org/) together and I'm having a hard time remembering to have to use **Command-C** when on my 3rd screen (the mac machine), and **Control-C** when on my 1st and 2nd screens (the windows machine).

As such, when I'm on my Mac (in other words when my mouse is in my 3rd screen), I'm trying to remap **Left-Control** to **Command** -- so that no matter which computer I have active, I will always hit Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V on my keyboard.

- I've tried looking at Automator but it doesn't appear to have the settings I need.
- I've tried the **System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Modifier Keys** section, but that won't work either, because my keyboard and mouse are plugged into the windows machine -- my Mac doesn't technically have any keyboard or mouse attached at all... all the keystrokes are sent over Synergy.
- I've tried a program called "KeyRemap4MacBook", which also doesn't accomplish what I need, I suspect also because the keystrokes are sent over LAN via Synergy.

Is there anyway that I can get around this?

Your input is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The Synergy server settings will actually let you remap the keys.  Just open the Synergy server settings.  From that screen double click on one of the clients.  You should get a screen similar to this one:

[image]

From there you can remap the modifier keys however you please, and it should only take effect for the selected client.

Answer (score -1):

Incase anyones having trouble heres a working configuration that does what the OP asks

[sample synergy configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh2L4.png)

As per @DavidPostill request, the different information is that you MUST map both the *Control key* and the *Super key*, you cannot just change one of them. Also the picture uploaded shows an actual working configuration, not just the default configuration screen.

Also I would have embedded the image but I cant as I don't have enough rep

Comment: Why are you copying another answer? Please don't do that.

Comment: how did i copy another answer?

Comment: @DavidPostill, i posted a sample config because you must re-map both the Ctrl AND the Super key, you cant just change ctrl to map to super. not sure why you would be trolling old msg boards and downvoting for no reason. i added it incase it helps someone else, why did you post your comment, it doesnt help anyone

Comment: Your image is almost identical to the one in the other answer (apart from the "Screen Name") - and your answer also does not provide any extra information like the other one does. Now if you expand you answer to include some explanation it would be better.

Comment: no its not identical, put on your glasses.

Comment: I said almost identical.

Comment: but theres a purpose to my post. i didnt get the config working at first. only took a second for me to realize whats wrong, but this may help someone else who needs it. pls remove downvote as i did not copy an answer but provided additional details that may be useful.

Comment: Please update the answer to add the important extra information from your comment above.

Comment: By the way, It's not my downvote.